# Input control type Checkbox always true

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have searched all the topics discussing this issue and cant seem to find one that explains the issue using Asp.net C#, everything is either javascript or MVC or PHP my reasoning for opening a new question regarding this.

I have 2 input control type checkbox

```
<input runat="server" type="checkbox"  name="chkChildSexMale" id="chkChildSexMale" />
<input runat="server" type="checkbox" name="chkChildSexFemale" id="chkChildSexFemale"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveCheckBoxes" runat="server" Text="Save CheckBox" OnClick="btnSaveCheckBoxes_Click" />
```

****EDITED*****

```
protected void SaveCheckBoxes()
{
  if (chkChildSexMale.Checked)
      {
          do something
      }
      else if (chkChildSexFemale.Checked)
      {
          do something else
      }

}
```

Then in my button click event I call this method

```
protected void btnSaveCheckBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SaveCheckBoxes();
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `name=""`

Comment: I changed the name but that did not fix the issue the chkChildSexMale.Checked is always true even if it is not checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was on page load I was using my data reader to set the checkboxes based on certain values. Which when I clicked my button click it was over writing my selected values with values from the database. So I Had to add the if (!Page.IsPostBack)

Giving the information I provided it would have been really hard to figure out that so I thank all for trying to help

Answer (score 5):

You should be using input type radio, not checkbox, for two mutually exclusive selections:

```
<input runat="server" type="radio"  name="chkChildSex" value="male" id="chkChildSexMale" />
<input runat="server" type="radio" name="chkChildSex" value="female" id="chkChildSexFemale" />
```

When you use the same `name` attribute for two checkboxes, the second overrides the first. When you use the same `name` attribute for two radio buttons, it associates them and the value is the value of the checked item.

Comment: For this example I may be able to use radio buttons but I have more checkboxes that are behaving the same way and I can not use radio buttons for those would like to know why the .checked property is evaluating to true even though it is not checked. And I changed the name to be unique also and this is not working still

Answer (score 1):

Although the id attribute is different for both checkboxes the name attribute is the same.

Also, the suggestion about using radio buttons makes the most sense based on what it looks like you're trying to do.

```
<input runat="server" type="radio" name="rdoChildSex" value="Male" />
<input runat="server" type="radio" name="rdoChildSex" value="Female" />
```

---

Again, I would recommend going with the radio button example above when you need to pick between one of two options. But if you want to get radio-like functionality for checkboxes you can try this...

```
<input runat="server" type="checkbox" name="chkChildSexMale" value="Male" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" />
<input runat="server" type="checkbox" name="chkChildSexFemale" value="Female" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"/>

void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArge e)
{
    var checkbox = ((CheckBox)sender);       

    if (checkbox.Value == "Male")
    {
        chkChildSexFemale.Checked = false;
        chkChildSexMale.Checked = true;
        do something...
    }
    else
    {
        chkChildSexMale.Checked = false;
        chkChildSexFemale.Checked = ;
        do something else...
    }
}
```

The code above should REALLY cover all your bases. It is even somewhat overkill. But is should work.

---

Try changing your code to the following:

```
    if (chkChildSexMale.Checked == true)   
    {
         do something   
    }   
    else if (chkChildSexFemale.Checked == false)   
    {
         do something else   
    }
```

Comment: For this example I may be able to use radio buttons but I have more checkboxes that are behaving the same way and I can not use radio buttons for those would like to know why the .checked property is evaluating to true even though it is not checked. And I changed the name to be unique also and this is not working still

Comment: Where in your code are you performing the check? In PageLoad?

Comment: on button click event

Comment: Did you see the updated example that I gave? It really shouldn't make a difference whether you use the "== true" and "== false" or simply use ".Checked" but stranger things have happened.

Comment: Yes initially I had this code which did not work because the .Checked is evaluating to true

Comment: Why don't you add a CheckChanged event to your checkboxes and in the Check_Changed method explicitly set the values of the checkboxes to the correct values?

Comment: If checkbox.Value does not exist when I try this way